# performance improvement: toString()

Tags: java, performance, tostring

We are developing quite big server app. Each action is tracked by log. There are many logs with calling of toString method. Unfortunatelly we need most of them on other hand we cannot track what happens on prod. 
Is it make sense trying to improve toString method? Forexample put result of toString in memory and update if some field was updated.

```
example of my toString
public classs InMessage{
//declared 20+ fields
     @Override
      public String toString() {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
       builder.append(": [");
       builder.append(super.toString());
       builder.append("; updateTime: ");
       builder.append(updateTime);
       //forexample 20 fields here
       builder.append(";]");
       return builder.toString();
     }}
then we process InMessage in some way and log each action
     log.debug("We received inMessage: {}", inMessage);
```

after this discussion we decided to decrease number of logs where it's possible and nothing more.

Comment: This depends on the implementation of your tostring method, we ca'n only guess. Maybe you need a stringbuilder... So add a sample implementation of a tostring method.

Comment: I don't understand your question..

Comment: Why log for calling `toString`?

Comment: could you please elaborate ? on what objects you do the toString call ? Indeed toString can be a time consuming action.

Comment: if you think about it, the toString() keeps much less time than the time needed to write the string on the disk. Are you sure that it is the logging slowing down your server? (I don't think so but) then try to refactor the logging system to log just what you need to track production problems. verbose != good

Comment: I suppose that by "put result of toString in memory and update if some field was updated" you mean caching of the toString() result for later use, right?

Comment: caching of the toString() result for later use, right.

Exactly

Answer (score 8):

Unless you are actively experiencing performance or memory issues, don't worry about it.  Useful logs can help enormously in prod diagnostics, you need to weigh that against hypothetical performance worries that might just never happen.

(Not saying you're definitely going to be problem-free here, just don't optimise for something that's not *really* a problem...)

Edit: trust your own judgement on whether you're logging "too much"; if a single UI or service operation generates 20 pages of incidental / debug level information, even at INFO level logging, you might want to refine the content to make it genuinely useful

Comment: Mostly you are right. Just thinking aloud  it's make sence to improve such thing or not

Comment: "Premature optimisation" is a well known term that it you might find interesting to learn about.  It's not universally accepted but interesting reading! Links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize  http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451

Comment: actually it's not premature. we process above million messages per day. There are really a lot logs))

Comment: Sure; question is though, is that a *problem*? Or just has a bit of a smell to it :-)  "Problem" could mean technical: using too much disk space, or "softer": team can't see real issues due to noise. Sounds like you guys maybe would benefit from reviewing logging volumes though FWIW, I would agree that could well be appropriate at this point.

Comment: @Diyko if you have serveral million messages per day, how do you do anything usefull with then? In good logging frameworks you can switch on and off logging for different compoments and put then in seperate logs. If you just gather everything you will search your log of hours to find the problem. So only do logging on the parts you have problems with and only messages which can help to solve it.

Comment: A few options; grep for unique customer / product / operation IDs which you record with each entry via, say, Nested Diagnostic Contexts in Log4J.  Timestamp greps, e..g all operations at '2013-02-15 09:47'.  ERROR greps, WARN greps. Greps where messages contain '.. order received at ...'. But yeah, Too Much Logging is Too Much Logging :-)

Comment: @peer we use logback and some analyze tool for log so it's not a problem to read it.

Comment: @Brian It's not a problem, just a bit of a smell :-)

Answer (score 3):

That nano-optimization usually ends up in useless effort that add no overall value with the exception of some ms substracted from a time handled in seconds or, sometimes, minutes. Depends on the case but yours could be one of those where every little bit counts.

Identify an optimization need based on data, don't pre-optimize and in particular with such methods. I bet there are other approaches that could prove more valuable than questioning the use of `toString` like, for example, improving the order of a commonly used algorith or reducing the load of an operation (less calls, but significant ones).

Just compare the usage of `toString` with the solution you have in mind, you're implementing a kind of observer pattern that updates a central string repository if a field is changed? That's executing code on every setter (if you use that approach).